# How do I move the menu items to the left using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my site: http://91.109.247.178/~brasseriegalway/

How do I move the menu element to left and align all of them like the attachment using jQuery.

This is what I did to move the logo in between the menu bar.

```
jQuery("#menubar-brand").insertAfter(jQuery('.menu-list-right').children()[3]);
```

[link to the attachment](http://uploadpie.com/aJDci)
Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not split the menu in two different areas and position the logo inbetween them using css? That way you don't need to use jquery to dynamically position the menu and logo

Comment: yea I tried that, but this is a wordpress site and as you would know, the code in wordpress  theme is not like sites build the old school way. 

So, thats why I used the jQuery to move the logo in between and was hoping to re-position the menu elements accordingly.

Comment: You could use Jquery to add styles to the elements $('##menubar-brand').css({});